# iPad orientation bug in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, orientation

I am getting a strange error when launching my app in iPad running on iOS 8 (only if launched in landscape mode). Though, it works very fine in iOS 7

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcJJ1.jpg

The app is fully portrait mode except one screen (graph which requires both portrait & landscape modes) and so I can't uncheck landscape property in deployment target. If I uncheck landscape orientation support in deployment target then it works very fine. So it works fine when I launch in iPad with iOS 8 (ONLY if it is portrait mode). If I launch it in landscape mode it shows this black strip (which is exactly the area which keyboard takes but there no keyboard, neither I'm showing it on this screen).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Are you using spritebuilder?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem. Locked screen to landscape. Launched my vertical-only app and same problem as you are seeing.